# Use promise in directive for dynamic templateUrl

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-promise

I have a promise SharedData which return a variable service .template as well. The value is mytemplate with which I build an url that I ant to pass to templateUrl directive but without success.

```
app.directive('getLayout', function(SharedData) {

var buildUrl= '';

SharedData.then(function(service) {
    buildUrl = service.template + '/layouts/home.html';
    console.log(buildUrl); // return mytemplate/layouts/home.html which is the URL I want to use as templateUrl
});

return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {...},
    templateUrl: buildUrl
}
});
```

Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolve my issue using [$templateRequest](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateRequest)

```
app.directive('getLayout', function($templateRequest, SharedData) {

return {

    restrict: 'A',

    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        SharedData.then(function(service) {

            myTemplate = $templateRequest(service.template + '/layouts/home.html');

            Promise.resolve(myTemplate).then(function(value) {
                element.html(value);
            }, function(value) {
                // not called
            });
        });
      }
    };
});
```

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZsFjr3UWnn3DnjD6Ad5O?p=preview)

Hope this will help some people :) and thanks to @Matthew Green

Comment: I had to add "$compile(element.contents())(scope);" after "element.html(value);"

Answer (score 1):

[The docs seem to say that the templateUrl can be set asynchronously.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object) However, I have not been able to show that applies to promises. So one way you can do this then while still using a promise would be to add the template to your element in the `link` function instead.

That would look something like this.

```
  app.directive('getLayout', function($templateCache, SharedData) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        SharedData.then(function(templateName) {
          element.html($templateCache.get(templateName));
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

[Here is a plunkr to show a full working example.](http://plnkr.co/edit/JtDET2gFAB8K92JWtHsA?p=info) It assumes that the template is loaded into `$templateCache` so if it isn't you can do a `$http.get()` for the same effect.

Comment: What doesn't work? Are you getting an error? Is the template not loading?

Comment: Sorry, the template is not loading. I get 2 errors Error. First is undefined is not an object (evaluating 'b.protocol') and second refer to https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/tpload?p0=undefined

Comment: I had a console.log(service.template) in templateUrl fct and it well return mytemplate… strange !

Comment: I've changed directions a little bit since I couldn't get an example app working either. Let me know if this update is closer.

Comment: I have done this http://plnkr.co/edit/ZsFjr3UWnn3DnjD6Ad5O?p=preview where I am able to load a template through controller but not with the get-layout directive to load template1.html file

Comment: The issue with your plunkr is that you are still trying to use a promise for the templateUrl and that doesn't seem to work. You need to do something closer to what I showed above where you resolve the promise and then manually compile it.